# Explode and return first element of array with one line of code

Tags: php, string

```
   $domain_parts = explode('.', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_GET['domain']));
   $sld = $domain_parts[0];
```

I am wanting to do the functionality of lines 1 and 2 into 1 line of code.

An example of what `$_GET['domain']` provides is `google.com`

What is the cleanest way to do this in one line.

Comment: What's the obsession with fitting the most functionality onto one line?

Comment: Or you could always install php 5.4 and just write `explode(...)[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it without regular expression like this

```
$sld = str_replace(' ','',substr($_GET['domain'],0,strpos($_GET['domain'],'.')));
```

Comment: Yes. `preg_replace` needs lot of resource. and is not for replacing just a space. If you don't need the power of regular expressions don't use `preg_` functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `list` like

```
list($domain_parts) = explode('.', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_GET['domain']));
```

It will directly returns the `$domain_parts[0]`.You can also try with `strtok` like

```
echo strtok(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_GET['domain']),  '.');
```

See this [**STRTOK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
list($domain_parts) = explode('.', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_GET['domain']));
```

`$domain_parts` will contain the first element of the array.

You could get the second element like this:-

```
list(,$domain_parts) = explode('.', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_GET['domain']));
```

See [list()](http://php.net/list) for more details.

Or you could do this:-

```
$domain_parts = explode('.', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_GET['domain']))[0];
```

if you have PHP >= 5.4